# Install SSRS Automatically

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

How can we install Sql server Reporting services 2019 automatically?using cmd/ powershell commands? i tried following but it doesn't work

***>SQL2019-SSEI-Eval.exe  /IACCEPTSQLSERVERLICENSETERMS  /ACTION=install /FEATURES=RS /RSINSTALLMODE="FilesOnlyMode"   /InstanceName=MSSQLSERVER /RSSVCACCOUNT="NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE" /INSTANCEDIR="C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server"***

Answer (score 0):

Using PowerShell and assuming your installer is **Setup.exe** in *C:\SSRS*

```
$pathvargs = {C:\SSRS\Setup.exe /q /IACCEPTSQLSERVERLICENSETERMS /ACTION="install" /ERRORREPORTING=1 /UPDATEENABLED="False" /INSTANCENAME="MSSQLSERVER" /FEATURES="RS" /RSINSTALLMODE="DefaultNativeMode" /SQLSVCACCOUNT="[DOMAIN\ACCOUNT]" /SQLSVCPASSWORD="[PASSWORD]" /AGTSVCACCOUNT="[DOMAIN\ACCOUNT]" /AGTSVCPASSWORD="[PASSWORD]" /SQLSYSADMINACCOUNTS="[DOMAIN\ACCOUNT]" }
Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock $pathvargs
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/install-windows/install-reporting-services-at-the-command-prompt?view=sql-server-2016#examples-of-native-mode-installation